# Index of the items that have the most addition and subtraction

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api, .net-core

I have two arrays and I want to find the index of the items that have the most addition and subtraction. for example:

```
var arrayA = new int[] { 1, -2, 3, 4, 15, 7, 9, 2 };
var arrayB = new int[] { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 11 };
```

I want the output to be as follows:

```
SUM: value: 27, index of A: 4, index of B: 5
SUBTRACT: value: 14, index of A: 1, index of B: 5
```

I can do this by using a loop over two arrays

```
int SUM=-1000;
int IndexA = 0;
int IndexB = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arrayA.Count(); i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < arrayB.Count(); j++)
    { 
        if(arrayA[i]+ arrayB[j] > SUM)
        {
             SUM = arrayA[i] + arrayB[j];
             IndexA = i;
             IndexB = j;
        }
            
    }
Console.WriteLine("SUM: value: " + SUM.ToString() + ", index of A: " + 
                 IndexA.ToString() + ", index of B: " + IndexB.ToString());


int SUBTRACT = -1000;
int _IndexA = 0;
int _IndexB = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arrayA.Count(); i++)
   for (int j = 0; j < arrayB.Count(); j++)
   {
       if (arrayA[i] - arrayB[j] > SUBTRACT)
       {
            SUBTRACT = arrayA[i] - arrayB[j];
            _IndexA = i;
            _IndexB = j;
       }

       if ( arrayB[j] - arrayA[i] > SUBTRACT)
       {
             SUBTRACT = arrayB[j] - arrayA[i];
             _IndexA = i;
             _IndexB = j;
       }

   }
Console.WriteLine("SUBTRACT: value: " + SUBTRACT.ToString() + ", index of A: " + _IndexA.ToString() + ", index of B: " + _IndexB.ToString());
```

Is this the right solution? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sort the arrays with index, there is no need for loop over two arrays. You `choose the largest of each array` for `SUM`:

```
var ListA = arrayA.Select((x, i) => new { value = x, Index = i }).OrderBy(x=>x.value).ToList();
var ListB = arrayB.Select((x, i) => new { value = x, Index = i }).OrderBy(x=>x.value).ToList();

Console.WriteLine("SUM:{0}, index of A: {1}, index of B: {2}", ListA[ListA.Count - 1].value+
                 ListB[ListB.Count - 1].value, ListA[ListA.Count - 1].Index, ListB[ListB.Count - 1].Index);
```

> SUM:27, index of A: 4, index of B: 5

To `subtract`, compare the `largest item from arrayA with the smallest item from arrayB` (or largest item from arrayB with the smallest item from arrayA):

```
if ((ListA[ListA.Count - 1].value - ListB[0].value) >= (ListB[ListB.Count - 1].value - ListA[0].value))
    Console.WriteLine("SUBTRACT: {0}, index of A: {1}, index of B: {2}", ListA[ListA.Count - 1].value - ListB[0].value, ListA[ListA.Count - 1].Index, ListB[0].Index);
else
    Console.WriteLine("SUBTRACT: {0}, index of A: {1}, index of B: {2}", ListB[ListB.Count - 1].value - ListA[0].value, ListA[0].Index, ListB[ListB.Count - 1].Index);
```

> SUBTRACT: 14, index of A: 1, index of B: 5

Comment: Sorting has `O(n log(n))` time cost, while this task only needs a linear `O(n)` time cost to be solved. Therefore this is not an ideal solution.

Comment: @Lucero All items from the A list should be compared to all items from the B list. That is mean O(n^2)...how to solve this problem with O(n) time complexity?

Comment: In order to solve the problem you only need to know the largest and the smallest element (and its index) of the A list, and the largest (and its index) in the B list. Finding these requires a single pass through each list only, thus `O(n)` time complexity (and `O(1)` space complexity).

Comment: (The solution for the addition is adding the largest items of each the A and B lists, white the solution for subtraction is subtracting the largest item from the B list from the smallest in the A list. There is no need to compute all possible combinations!)